# Hodge theory in general

Tags: differential-geometry, hodge-theory

I know a bit of Hodge theory, and I know that there is an analogue in the symplectic case, where instead of inducing the $\star$-product using the metric we use the symplectic form. Is in true in general that if we have a linear isomorphism
$$\phi:T^*M\longrightarrow TM,$$
then we can define an associated $\star$-product and derive a Hodge theory for it? In particular, I'm interested in the study of deRham cohomology using such a generalised theory.

Comment: [Related](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.5418)

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks for the reference. Mmh so it doesn't even work well in the symplectic case... Do you know by any chance if there is a good way to work in the (deRham) cohomology of a Poisson manifold?